# Sharepoint Online Office 365 Search custom file types index

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, search-results

I am using an Office 365 Sharepoint online license and I am trying to add new file types to index for the search feature.

I couldn't find anything explaining how to do this in Sharepoint Online.
I found a few things about Sharepoint Server, but there's no such thing as **Manage service applications** or **Search Service Application** anywhere in admin center.

Is there a way to do this in Sharepoint Online or is it just impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the file types in Office 365. Though to get to Search Settings for you tenant to manage other aspects f search go to the SharePoint Admin Center and click Search.