# Opening .DWG files in SharePoint online search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-search

Hope there is a fix for this;

There is a WebViewer for Autocad (.DWG) files. When opening them in a doc library, there are no issues.

However, if i search for a .DWG file, and try opening it there, it will just go to the property page of that file.

Is there any way to add the file-extension to the search index, so that it will open in the webviewer?
i found tutorials about SP2010/SP2013, but nothing for SPOnline

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't change file types from search index in Office 365 SharePoint Online. There is no setting to configure it in SharePoint Online Admin Center.

A similar thread: [Sharepoint Online Office 365 Search custom file types index](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221758/sharepoint-online-office-365-search-custom-file-types-index)